# Unable to add to Firebase table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Below is the rule.

```
  {
      "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
```

Here is the code I am using to add. The line `mAuth,getCurrentUser.isAnonymous` returned false and userid also printed the value. The user is authenticated but unable to write to users table.

```
System.out.println("Anonymous - "+ mAuth.getCurrentUser().isAnonymous());
mRef = new Firebase("https://moe-90cc7.firebaseio.com/users");
String userid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
System.out.println("userid---" + userid);
mRef.child(userid).setValue("1");
```

When I change rule to

```
read: true
write: true
```

it works fine, but the point is why its not working with `auth!=null` rule when I am authenticated user.

Is there anything I can do to double check if the user is authenticated or not?

Comment: You're mixing Firebase versions 2.x (e.g. `new Firebase(...`) and 9.x/10.x (e.g. `mAuth.getCurrentUser()`). So while you have an authenticated user in Firebase 9.x/10.x, your connection to the database is unauthenticated. The solution is to make sure you use Firebase 9.x/10.x exclusively and remove the dependency on Firebase 2.x from you gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have to authenticate user which is updating realtime database. you can authenticate user via some login methods as provided by google.

you can check [this link for gmail authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

Comment: I am already using Google authentication. I think that this line mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(); itself proves that I am authenticated..

Comment: It returns the valid key and the account also got added on firebase authentication UI

Comment: i think you have to include the authenticated account in you realtime database project then only you can be authenticated i guess.

Comment: go to authentication tab in firebase and you will get sign-in methods and users. i hope you understand.

Comment: They are already added on the firebase UI.. I  am able to add records to location table but not able to add to user table ..

Comment: if you are able to add in one table and not in other then there is something wrong with your key which you are passing or check your table name.
but you can check if account which you are using to login must be added in user.

Comment: How to check that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131662/discussion-between-vahqiav-and-user7327850).